# How to remove terms from a boolean string that are not present in a given list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, boolean-logic

I have a boolean string and a list of terms. All terms are standardized to be a single word `[a-z0-9_]`.

I want to write a helper function that takes in the boolean string and a list of terms and removes the terms that are not present in the given list. Consequently, the relevant components surrounding the term in the boolean string should also be removed (and/or/not, etc)

Example -

```
>>> boolean_string = '(term_a or term_b) and (not term_c and not term_d)'

>>> term_list = ['term_a', 'term_d']

>>> helper_func(boolean_string, term_list)
```

The output should be -

```
>>> term_a and (not term_d)
```

`term_b` and `term_c` are removed since they are not present in the given `term_list`.  Also, note that `or` preceding `term_b` has also been removed since it would no longer be relevant.

Similarly, `not` and `and` surrounding `term_c` were also removed.

The helper function should be able to handle different boolean string scenarios.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: "boolean string" isn't a thing and for a good reason. Use a proper data format.

Comment: You need to write a little lexer and parser. What have you tried so far?